# SPO - Share Document Link Broken Sometimes

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

[image]
We recently rolled out our first Intranet on SPO/O365 and users are starting to email colleagues with links to documents. They are using the **Share/Get a link** method. Sometimes the resulting link leads to the "Sorry..." message that the document may have been moved or deleted, which is not the case. Many times when the link is re-created, it works. I 'could' ask them to use the **Share/Invite People** method, but sometimes a link is part of a more elaborate email that Personal Message just can't handle. Any thoughts as to why this happens and how to prevent it? Thank you!

Comment: @BennySkogberg we are using E2 Charity licenses. I've added a screenshot to my original question above. Thank you.